# Combine the content of multiple columns from the result of a query

Tags: sql, hana

My problem is being able to combine the content of 2 columns that contain similar data with two other columns with similar data. The problem is that I want to do it with the result of a fairly long query, so the tables are not saved to perform a union function.

Input data:

| column a | column b | column c | column d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | d | g | j |
| b | e | h | k |
| c | f | i | l |

Desired result:

| column a | column b |
| --- | --- |
| a | d |
| b | e |
| c | f |
| g | j |
| h | k |
| i | l |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic solution is `union all`:

```
select a, b
from t
union all
select c, d
from t;
```

You can use a CTE to express this:

```
with cte as (
      <subquery here>
     )
select a, b
from cte
union all
select c, d
from cte;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your answer, this is the solution that I know but in this case "t" is a query of more than 400 lines, you know if there is a way to do it without repeating "t" 2 times.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, I just thought that union all would also include the duplicate values for me, however, I had to add an ID column to bring absolutely all the data if I didn't do this the result would eliminate the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will be any easier to implement than Gordon's answer, but another possible approach is as follows:

```
WITH TwoRows AS
   (SELECT 1 as RowNo UNION SELECT 2 as RowNo)

SELECT
   CASE WHEN cte.RowNo = 1 THEN t.Column_A ELSE t.Column_C END AS Column_A
   CASE WHEN cte.RowNo = 1 THEN t.Column_B ELSE t.Column_D END AS Column_B
FROM
   TwoRows cte
   CROSS JOIN MyTable t
```